# Error in attaching image, low memory

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my code.

```
case RESULT_MEMORY_SELECT:       //SELECTING IMAGE FROM SD CARD
                 Uri photoUri = data.getData();
                 String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();
                        Bitmap imageReturned = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                        showViewOfReceiptInLayout(imageReturned);
                    }
                    break;


public void showViewOfReceiptInLayout(Bitmap imageBitmap)
        {
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
             imageSelected = baos.toByteArray();  // imageSelected is byteArray and i am storing this byte array in Database
             imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 72, 72, false);
             image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // For Visible 
             image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


02-29 10:30:44.496: E/AndroidRuntime(7682): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
02-29 10:30:44.496: E/AndroidRuntime(7682):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
02-29 10:30:44.496: E/AndroidRuntime(7682):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
02-29 10:30:44.496: E/AndroidRuntime(7682):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
```

Can anyone tell how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution where you have to shrink the size of image to avoid out of memory.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=options.outWidth, height_tmp=options.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        Bitmap btm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);
       img_t.setImageBitmap(btm);
```

Comment: won't it lose the quality? i don't want to reduce the size and quality of image that i am going to store in database

Comment: it will but you have no other option dear as per my opinion

Answer (score 0):

first, you need find the oom reason:

if your application memory usage is big before decode the image, so before decode image you need release some memory, release the object reference if you dont use the object.

you can use: `adb shell dumpsys meminfo your_package_name` to display the memory useage

if the application memory usage is small before decode image, the oom is the decode image occur, if this happen, suggestion:

1.if your image is bigger, when decode, supply a [BitmapFactory.Option](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html), the option has a [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to use small memory to decode image

2.make the try block around the decode method, catch the [OutOfMemroyError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)